# java : read/write neo4j server database

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, resultset

I want to connect to a remote neo4j database, so I put this as a server.
Until now, I try to connect through jdbc, but the only jar I found has some issues. The most important one : Each time I ask for the next resultset (resultset.next()), and there is not anymore, I got this message in my console :

> Unexpected token END_ARRAY
>   errors-next-token = FIELD_NAME
>   null

Well, since I send something like 20 requests to server per second, It becomes easily horrible!
Has anyone another solution to solve this problem (I'm 100% open minded!)

Thanks a lot.
Niko

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in neo4j-jdbc and has been fixed. Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/issues/8) which exactly matches your case.